# Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings on a simple servlet code

Tags: servlets

I'm trying to learn using servlets and JSPs.  I wanted to test out how it worked through NetBeans (using Glassfish Server). I created a web project (Java Ant for Web) and added a servlet. I didn't modify it heavily as I was only testing. I deployed it and the index.jsp worked but when I try accessing the servlet through the mapping, I am getting a HTTP 500 error.

> **exception** jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class test.MyDateServlet
>
> **root cause** java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> **root cause** java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyDateServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.MyDateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyDateServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyDateServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

MyDateServlet.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author FE
 */
public class MyDateServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MyDateServlet (Servlet version) </title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Today's date is:  " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println(new java.util.Date());
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

This is a really simple code with minimal revisions but I'm not too sure why I'm getting the error. My java is updated, and I'm currently using Java EE 7 API in my library.

Comment: Your Java is updated to what? Java EE has been rebranded to Jakarta EE (and all of the packages changed). So you need to be very clear about your versions in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve mixed major versions of the Servlet technology.

A few years ago Oracle donated its Java EE specifications and technologies to the Eclipse Foundation. These were rebranded *Jakarta EE*.

As part of the transition, the package names changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. I see both of these in your Question, so I know you have a major mixup in your versions of API and libraries. Choose one or the other, but not both.

You need to get your API, libraries/dependencies, and deployment container all in alignment. Either you need to use older versions with `javax.` naming, or newer versions using `jakarta.* naming. If you are starting out on a fresh product, I would recommend the latter.

Search to learn more about this transition. It has been covered many many times in many many places including in the industry press, YouTube, and the [Jakarta.EE](https://jakarta.ee) web site.

While I’m not 100% certain this transition mismatch is the cause of your troubles, I would bet money on it.